# How to create a new Bitbucket pull request via API?

Tags: powershell, bitbucket, bitbucket-server, bitbucket-api

I'm trying to create a pull request on Bitbucket Server via Rest API, following [this documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/bitbucket/rest/v815/api-group-pull-requests/#api-api-latest-projects-projectkey-repos-repositoryslug-pull-requests-post). No matter what I try, I get a `(400) Bad Request.` error. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64037754/22146392) and used the body text from the answer (of course, replacing my information like the repo, branch, etc.):

```json
{
    "title": "My new PR",
    "description": "This is my new PR.",
    "state": "OPEN",
    "open": true,
    "closed": false,
    "fromRef": {
        "id": "refs/heads/this-is-my-branch",
        "repository": {
            "slug": "my-repo",
            "name": 'My repo',
            "project": {
                "key": "KE"
            }
        }
    },
    "toRef": {
        "id": "refs/heads/master",
        "repository": {
            "slug": "my-repo",
            "name": 'My repo',
            "project": {
                "key": "KE"
            }
        }
    },
    "locked": false,
    "reviewers": [
        {
            "user": {
                "name": "jeremywat"    
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the request (I'm using PowerShell):

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $BasicAuth"} -Body $JsonBody -ContentType 'application/json' -Method POST -Uri https://my-bitbucket-server.com/rest/api/1.0/projects/KE/repos/my-repo/pull-requests
```

The example provided in the Atlassian documentation includes some additional information in the request body and I tried including all that info as well, but still receive the same `(400) Bad Request.` error.

I know the credentials (`$BasicAuth`) are correct because I can get PRs, comment on PRs, etc. via the API with the same credentials. I can also create a new PR from the Bitbucket web interface.

So can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong and what's the correct way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I was putting the `project` node inside the `repository` node (which is how it's done in [the documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/bitbucket/rest/v815/api-group-pull-requests/#api-api-latest-projects-projectkey-repos-repositoryslug-pull-requests-post-example)). Looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66849804/22146392), the project and repository nodes are separate elements so I tried that and it worked this time:

```json
{
    "title": "My new PR",
    "description": "This is my new PR.",
    "state": "OPEN",
    "open": true,
    "closed": false,
    "fromRef": {
        "id": "refs/heads/this-is-my-branch",
        "repository": "my-repo",
        "project": {
            "key": "KE"
        }
    },
    "toRef": {
        "id": "refs/heads/master",
        "repository": "my-repo",
        "project": {
            "key": "KE"
        }
    },
    "locked": false,
    "reviewers": [
        {
            "user": {
                "name": "jeremywat"    
            }
        }
    ]
}
```